# How can I post data on online and request data for Login and SingUp system

Tags: javascript, web, fetch

I am new in javascript how can I do I can't find an API please help me also how can I post or request I didn't know . i am really confuse because I cant find api or other why to store data and get data  and other method I know is localstorage but this is not safe way to do .

**There is my code***

````
function singup() {
    var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('singupemail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('singupPass').value;
    //var userpass = document.getElementById('username').value + document.getElementById('singupPass').value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value;
 // i dont know why this is not working [if (user == '' && email == '' && password == '' )]
   
    if (user == "") {
        alert("Please fill all the fields");
    }
    else if (email == "") {
        alert("Please fill all the fields");
    }
    else if (password == "") {
        alert("Please fill all the fields");
    }
    else {

        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            alert("Passwords do not match");
        }

        else if (user === localStorage.getItem('username') || email === localStorage.getItem('email')) {
            alert("Your account already exists. Login Your account");
        }
        else if (user !== localStorage.getItem('usernamme')) {
            localStorage.setItem('username', user);
            localStorage.setItem('email', email);
            localStorage.setItem('password', password);
            alert("Sign Up Successful");
        }


    }
}```
````